# Avoiding repeated code in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query that works similar to this one:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN A = 1 THEN 'one'
    WHEN A = 2 THEN 'two'
  END AS Number
FROM [table]
WHERE
  A = 1
  OR A = 2
```

In the real query the comparison is more complex and there are more columns but for the question it shouldn't matter

Any way, I'm wondering if there is a some nice way to only make the comparison in one of the locations but still get the same result?

Comment: You could create a mapping table with the necessary data and join it.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Was kinda interested if there was a way to do it in the query. But i guess that is making things complicated for no reason. Thanks anyway

Comment: You could do a 'virtual table' instead of a real table and use that as a mapping table, i.e. you join to this table `(select 1 as c1, 'one' as c2 union all select 2,'two') As VirtualTable`. But it's a bad idea - always use a mapping table.

Comment: Perhaps you mean the simple case statement rather than the searched case statement: case a when 1 then 'one' when 2 then 'two' else 'something else' end